# Array reference deduction in template lambdas

Tags: c++, g++, c++20, clang++

I wrote a simple lambda function to copy one static size array into another

```
#include <tuple>
#include <iostream>


int main() {
    constexpr auto copyArray = [](auto& out, const auto& in) noexcept {
        [&]<size_t... Idxs>(std::index_sequence<Idxs...>) noexcept {
            ((out[Idxs]=in[Idxs]), ...);
        }(std::make_index_sequence<std::min(std::size(out), std::size(in))>());
    };

    constexpr char c1[] = "dfjkwhjifehuiqh3iuhuihf3enewlknek32    ";
    char c2[255]{0};
    copyArray(c2, c1);
    std::cout << (std::string(c2) == std::string(c1)) << "\n";
}
```

[The live example](https://godbolt.org/z/azTvjdhPr)

It works fine with GCC, but fails to compile with clang/msvc.

The error says `non-type template argument is not a constant expression`, which basically means clang can't figure out the size of `in` and `out`, but only if use `std::size`,  `sizeof` gives the right result (the compiler understands "the real" size of the arrays).

As I understand both `in` and `out` defined as references and should be deduced as `char(&)[40]` and `char(&)[255]`, so the size should be visible at compile time.

Is it clang/msvc issue?

Comment: function parameters are not constant expressions.  here is a workaround: https://godbolt.org/z/G9q7KvT34

Comment: This is an interesting issue, but you don't really need the lambda, you can just use `std::copy()` (so the `index_sequence` trick isn't necessary, just a `for` loop is enough).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is my favorite weird constexpr issue: [the constexpr array size problem](https://brevzin.github.io/c++/2020/02/05/constexpr-array-size/) resolved by [P2280](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2022/p2280r4.html) (note: this is my blog post and my paper).

The short version is that `std::size(in)` didn't used to be valid for use in a constant expression simply because `in` is a reference that is unknown to the constant evaluator. That's now changed - you don't actually need to read through `in` in any way to find the answer, so there's nothing that should prevent that from working. gcc apparently implements the fix here, clang does not yet.

Until then, you can change the lambda declaration to:

```cpp
constexpr auto copyArray = []<class T, size_t M, size_t M>(T (&out)[M], T const (&in)[M]) noexcept {
```

And then use `M` and `N` instead of `std::size(out)` and `std::size(in)`, respectively. Or any number of other workarounds (including just using `decltype(in)` and passing that to `std::extent`, etc.)

Comment: Simpler workaround is to use `std::copy_n(in, std::min(std::size(out), std::size(in)), out);` :-)

Comment: This post is being [discussed on Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/427730/).

Comment: @Jarod42 Manual solution is able to get shit done way more efficiently(that was pretty much the whole point of this function) https://godbolt.org/z/4oYnrc3h7